# Share x-axis between Bokeh plots

Tags: python, bokeh

In matplotlib you can share the x-axis between plots like so:

```
plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True)
```

I would like to do something similar in Bokeh, where I zoom one, the other will follow, etc. How would I do that in Bokeh?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is documented in the [Linking Plots](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/linking.html#userguide-interaction-linking) section of the User's Guide. You only need to share ranges objects:

```
p1 = figure()

# share just the x-range between these plots
p2 = figure(x_range=p1.x_range)
```